# Error De Sintaxis al crear procedimiento almacenado para mostrar campos

Tags: sql-server-2014

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado de una consulta para mostrar campos de una tabla pero al momento de ejecutarla marca error

esta seria la consulta

```
select 
c.name Usuario 
from sys.columns c 
join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id  
Where t.name = 'Usuario' 
And c.Name ='IdUsuario' or c.Name = 'NombreUsuario'
```

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'ListarBuscarUsuario')
    Begin 
        Print 'El Procedimiento ListarBuscarUsuario >>Ya Existe<<'
    End
ELSE
    Begin 
        DECLARE @ListarBuscarUsuario varchar(255);
        SET @ListarBuscarUsuario = N'Create Procedure ListarBuscarUsuario as select c.name Usuario from sys.columns c join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id  Where t.name = "Usuario" And c.Name ="IdUsuario" or c.Name = "NombreUsuario"';
        EXEC(@ListarBuscarUsuario);
        Print 'Procedimiento ListarBuscarUsuario Fue Creada'
    End
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el error completo que te marca. Copia y pega el error como texto, en lo posible.

Comment: Where t.name = "Usuario" And c.Name ="IdUsuario" or c.Name = "NombreUsuario"' al momento de hacer la consulta si la hago "" marca erro y si la dejo en ´´ tambien

Comment: Eh, pero no la has ejecutado?

Comment: si con la consulta normal si, pero en la consulta almacenada no me compilaba por error de sintaxis que tenia que tener doble comilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar comillas dentro de comillas se deben escapar, en sql se hace usando doble comilla simple `''`.

```
SET @ListarBuscarUsuario = N'Create Procedure ListarBuscarUsuario as select
 c.name Usuario from sys.columns c join sys.tables t on c.object_id = 
t.object_id  Where t.name = ''Usuario'' And c.Name =''IdUsuario'' 
or c.Name = ''NombreUsuario''';
```

Comment: Gracias me Sirvio